# how to simulate changing a checkbox without calling the onChange Event

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm trying to simulate changing a check state but i get in a continous loop with its OnChange Event. Is there a workaround for this?

What i'm trying to do : Example:

```
     Widget widget = RenderEngine.getWidget("checkbox");
     widget.VALUE = "False";
     //do something
     //return to the previous state
     widget.VALUE = widgetPreviousValue;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to change the value for the code to run? Can you refactor it so that you can pass in the value instead of using the widget's value?

Answer (score 0):

In your onChange event, can you just check the source of the event?